# Macro Excel capturar redirecionamentos dos links

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

É possível criar uma macro que me copie os redirecionamentos que tenho em links nas células `A1:A100` ?

Por exemplo na célula `A1` tenho `www.pplware.com`, mas quando abrimos este url sou redirecionado para outro url `https://pplware.sapo.pt`

O que preciso é que a macro escreva este redirecionamento nas células `B1:B100`, é possível fazer isto ?

Comment: Chegou a montar algum código vba? Se tiver edite a pergunta e adicione ele.

Comment: Obrigado, já esta resolvido.

Answer (score 3):

O [axel-richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) já me consegui-o ajudar e esta a funcionar bem.

[image: Printscreen]

```
  Public Function testRedirect(oCell As Range) As String

   testRedirect = "Não Redireciona"

   strURL = oCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address

   WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

   Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
   oWinHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

   oWinHttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
   oWinHttp.send ""

   If oWinHttp.Status = 301 Then
    strResponseHeaders = oWinHttp.getAllResponseHeaders()
    For Each strResponseHeader In Split(strResponseHeaders, Chr(10))
     If Left(strResponseHeader, 9) = "Location:" Then
      testRedirect = "redirected to " & strResponseHeader
     End If
    Next
   End If

End Function
```